# Keryx 1.0 on Ubuntu 13.04 server

Tags: keryx

How can I install and use Keryx 0.9 on Ubuntu 13.04 server? Please help.

I have installed a new Ubuntu 13.04 box at home that does not have internet access. I need to use keryx 0.9 to create a profile of it so that I can download it's packages later on a windows 7 pc that has internet access.

I already downloaded keryx 0.9 and copied the files to my ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0):

To install Keryx, download the [deb](https://launchpad.net/keryx/stable/1.0-release/+download/keryx_1.0-public21_all.deb) file, and just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded(probably the Downloads folder),run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb
```

Once installed, run the application, and see [here](http://channikhabra.blogspot.com/2011/07/keryx-tutorial-download-software-for.html) and [here](http://www.linuxforu.com/2010/09/offline-package-install-linux-made-easy-keryx/) on how to use.

Now from what I heard from a friend that used Kyrex, and he told me that it has some problems.  I haven't personally used it, since I use Synaptic instead, you may want to take a look at it.